# Getting error "Unexpected end of JSON input" for my API response processing in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm using the following code in my ReactJS project to process and return the REST API response.

```
function getImages() {
  const requestOptions = {
    method: 'GET',
    headers: { 'Content-Type' : 'application/json' },
  };

  return fetch(config.apiUrl + 'v1/image/fetch_images', requestOptions)
    .then(handleResponse, handleError)
    .then(backgroundImages => {
        return backgroundImages;
  });
}

function handleResponse(response) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {        
    if (response.ok) {
        var contentType = response.headers.get("content-type");
        if (contentType && contentType.includes("application/json")) {
            response.json().then(json => resolve(json)); //getting error in this line
        } else {
            resolve();
        }
    } else {
        response.text().then(text => reject(text));
    }
  });
}

function handleError(error) {
  return Promise.reject(error && error.message);
}
```

When I checked with postman I got the response as following and is in a json structure.

```
{
  "status": 200,
  "resp": [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "wintercityscape.jpg"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "powderbluesnow.jpg"
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "midnightsparkle.jpg"
    }
  ]
}
```

How can I fix this error? Thanks in advance..

Comment: Is `config.apiUrl` another origin? You might have CORS issues. Check the response in the Network tab of your Developer Tools.

Comment: Have you checked the actual response in your *code*?

Comment: `config.apiUrl` is fine. I'm not getting any response in my Network tab on Inspecting the element in browser. But getting the response in postman. For CORS I have used a chrome extension.

Comment: If you're not getting a response in your *code* then it's a code/CORS/etc. issue and you'll need to start there. That it works in Postman is somewhat immaterial.